# Have unpivot automatically grab column list (oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

This is a follow up question to [Transpose one row into many rows Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344403/transpose-one-row-into-many-rows-oracle)

I want to be able to unpivot an arbitrary query result.

To unpivot a table manually, I would do:

```
select value_type, value from (
 (
  -- query to be unpivoted
  -- EG: select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from table
 )
 unpivot
 (
  -- Line I would like to change
  value for value_type in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
 )
);
```

This works for all queries that return 5 columns, called `col1, col2`, etc.  Is there something I put in instead of `value for value_type in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)` that will grab all the column names from the query/view/table that is selected in the first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure to do this in PL/SQL by dynamically creating your SQL statement as a string an then using `execute immediate` to execute it and return a cursor.

Comment: Here is detailed answer with code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100101/unpivot-on-an-indeterminate-number-of-columns