# Give me column_name and column_value

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

do you know the function or procedure in oracle which would allow me the following:

```
TABLE Clients
COLUMN   id, name, vlag


columnname  column_value                   
id          1          
name        Jon         
flag        M         


columnname  column_value                   
id          2          
name        Jessica         
flag        F
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: example my table clients with columns id and name.
whether there is a function in oracle that would take this format for a given id
example select * from clients give a this result
'id name
1  jon
2  jessica'

I need the make columns (headers) to rows and columns to print the name of the column - Value column

Comment: @APC - It is called unpivoting not pivoting

Comment: What you're after is a form of transposing called unpivoting. StackOverflow already has lots of questions with answers on this topic. [Check out this search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+unpivot) . Different approaches suit different needs, for instance whether you have fixed table / column projection or a dynamic one.

Comment: @Prdp - quite right, I have posted a revised comment with a new search

Comment: @APC yes this is my answer, but my table is 200 column and this is very hard to manually typing sql :)  thank very mach

Answer (score 2):

```
with dat as (select '1' as id, 'Jon' as name, 'M' as vlag from dual union all
             select '2' as id, 'Jessica' as name, 'F' as vlag from dual)
select * from dat unpivot (column_value for column_name in (id, name, vlag));
```

But result will be pretty simmilar to previous answer (if you add there rownum and use as a key).

Comment: @Kasper  yes this is my answer, but my table is 200 column and this is very hard to manually typing sql :)  thank very mach

Comment: @nAPL try something like that: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot

Comment: thank this is my solutions 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100101/unpivot-on-an-indeterminate-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But I would say this is ineffecient

```
select  'id' as column_name, id as column_value from table
union all
select 'name',name from table
union all
select 'flag',vlag from table
```

Comment: not give me a like result