# Oracle 10G : How to convert multiple column values into rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have following table like this.

```
Sname   SUB1    SUB2    SUB3    MAR1    MAR2    MAR3
----------------------------------------------------
S001    HIN     ENG     ART     50      80      90
S002    ENG     ART     HIN     20      60      20
```

Now I need this above result in following format:

```
Sname       SUB     MARKS   
-----------------------------
S001        HIN     50
S001        ENG     80
S001        ART     90
S002        HIN     20
S002        ENG     20
S002        ART     60
```

How do I convert this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose one row into many rows Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344403/transpose-one-row-into-many-rows-oracle)

Comment: I have oracle 10g database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must query the table thrice and glue the results together:

```
select sname, sub1 as sub, mar1 as marks from mytable
union all
select sname, sub2 as sub, mar2 as marks from mytable
union all
select sname, sub3 as sub, mar3 as marks from mytable;
```

Comment: the table having 10 lac records or greater. what is the performance of this query.

Comment: The performance will be good, or at least as good as possible with the data model given. The dbms will most probably do exactly what the query suggests: read the whole table thrice and put one result after the other. What else should it do? There is no WHERE clause given, so all records must be read. And with the data in columns, you must read the table once per column. But the data will probably be in cache after the first read, so there will be no unnecessary disk reads.

Answer (score 1):

If you had version 11g or above, you could use `UNPIVOT` which would have been easy for this.

As you are using 10g, an alternative method is to generate three rows for each row in the main table:

```
select t.sname
     , case dummy.no
          when 1 then sub1
          when 2 then sub2
          when 3 then sub3
       end as sub
     , case dummy.no
          when 1 then mar1
          when 2 then mar2
          when 3 then mar3
       end as marks
from mytable t
cross join (
   select level no
   from dual
   connect by level <= 3
) dummy
```

`dummy` will contain three rows. `cross join` then makes the result have three rows for each row in `mytable`, and those three rows will have `dummy.no` values 1, 2 and 3.

Then in the `case` statements you pick out which values from `mytable` to use in the first row, the second row and the third row.