# how to transpose the queried results from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am wondering how I can write an Oracle sql command to show the query results instead as:

```
column_name1 column_name2  column_name3
result1_col1 result1_col2  result1_col3
result2_col1 result2_col2  result2_col3
...
```

but rather as:

```
column_name1 result1_col1  result2_col1 ...
column_name2 result1_col2  result2_col2 ...
column_name3 result1_col3  result2_col3 ...
```

?

My oracle version is 11.1.0.7.0.

Many thanks!

Comment: PIVOT can turn a SPECIFIC number of Rows into Columns.  If you want to do it without knowing how many columns you're going to end up with, you need to write code that writes code (aka dynamic sql).

Comment: This is what `PIVOT` does: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose select results with Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788011/transpose-select-results-with-oracle)

Comment: @dems I am also looking for the same query... can you please give some hint to do this , what you have suggested.. means that code.. if you have this kind of code/query with you please post here or please give any good link for this...

Comment: See the comment immediately before yours

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post of mine](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/pivot-queries.html) is rather old but does give a method for producing pivot queries dynamically.  It was written before the PIVOT clause existed.